# IOS app with Facebook Logon stuck at Logon page

Tags: ios, authentication, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am building a sample IOS test app with Facebook login and followed the instructions for the FB SDK to incorporate the FBSDKLoginButton. Clicking on the Login button does not bring up the Facebook logon options. Here is the code i have so far. What is the expected outcome? How best can i test this logon experience? how do i create a test FB account?

//In the view controller class

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
    loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
    loginButton.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:loginButton];
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
        // User is logged in, do work such as go to next view controller.
    }

}
```

//In the app delegate class

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [FBSDKLoginButton class];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
    /*return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

After setting up the plist as instructed try this.

```
  #import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

    - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
      [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
    }

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
      return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                      didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
    }

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
      return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                            openURL:url
                                                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                         annotation:annotation];
    }
```

Comment: I have this exact same piece of code. It doesn't work for some reason. Any other thoughts on what could be happening here?

Comment: Its difficult to determine with the given information. Were you able to run the sample iOS app given by facebook SDK?

Comment: Nope. The login integration is not working for some reason. Clicking on the fb login button does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the swift response, but it seems you have forgotten the delegate :

```
loginButton.delegate = self
```

don't forget to add FacebookDelegate in your class declaration and have 2 mandatory methods. There is a sample class in swift, i hope it will help you for your Obj-C issue.

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.mFacebookButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
        self.mFacebookButton.delegate = self
   }


    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
        self.checkIsLogged()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.checkIsLogged()
    }

    private func checkIsLogged(){
        if  (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil) {
        let permissions = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().permissions
        let token = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
        NSLog("\(permissions)")
        NSLog("\(token)")
    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {


    }
}
```